# What is the correct way to write out the scientific symbol µeV, microelectronvolts or microelectron-volts?

Tags: hyphenation, symbols, scientific-language

How should µeV be written out? Is it microelectronvolts? or microelectron-volts?

Comment: Depends on the context.

Comment: Wikipedia allows "electron volt", "electron-volt" or "electronvolt" for the base form; it's usual to put SI prefixes on without any hyphen. But in the absence of a house style, you can probably do what looks natural ("microelectronvolt" seems fine if you really can't use the symbol). See https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/208679/hyphenation-of-si-prefixes

Answer (score 2):

The *[Guide for the Use of the International System of Units (SI)](https://physics.nist.gov/cuu/pdf/sp811.pdf)* from NIST is useful for this.

In section 6.2.8 a relevant example is presented:

> Examples  of  the  use  of  prefix  symbols  with  eV  and  u  are  80
> MeV  (80  megaelectronvolts) and 15 nu (15 nanounified atomic mass
> units).